# How do I change the output of pandoc's markdown to html conversion

Tags: pandoc

So for example, if I do

```
# Header
```

pandoc gives out `<h1 id="header">Header</h1>`. I want something like

```
<h1 class="something" id="header">Header</h1>
```

Is there some file where I can change the html tag output in `$body$`?

Edit, I'm looking for a "natural" change (if that makes sense). So `# header` "naturally" gives back `<h1 class="classname">header</h1>`

I guess I'll look through the source code/docs for something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a class to all elements of a certain type, you could use a [filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html#json-filters). Here is one made with [panflute](https://github.com/sergiocorreia/panflute); let us save it as `add_class_to_header1.py`, and then compile the document with `pandoc mydoc.md -F add_class_to_header1.py -t ...`

```py
import panflute as pf


def add_class_to_header1(elem, doc):
    if isinstance(elem, pf.Header) and elem.level == 1:
        elem.classes = ["classname"]
    return elem


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pf.run_filter(add_class_to_header1)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
>echo # header {.something} | pandoc
<h1 id="header" class="something">header</h1>
```

If you want more info on how this works, check the section on `bracketed_spans` on the [manual](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), but in general adding `{.class}` to many objects will set their class.

Comment: You answered just as I was going to make an edit haha. I already know about adding `{.classname #idname}`. I was looking for a way of changing some config file or the source directly.